# Aggregate results of batch consumer in Camel (for example from SQS)

Tags: apache-camel, amazon-sqs

I'm consuming messages from SQS FIFO queue with `maxMessagesPerPoll=5` set.

Currently I'm processing each message individually which is a total waste of resources.
In my case, as we are using FIFO queue and all of those 5 messages are related to the same object, I could process them all toghether.

I though this might be done by using `aggregate` pattern but I wasn't able to get any results.

My consumer route looks like this:

```
from("aws-sqs://my-queue?maxMessagesPerPoll=5&messageGroupIdStrategy=usePropertyValue")
    .process(exchange -> {
        // process the message
    })
```

I believe it should be possible to do something like this

```
from("aws-sqs://my-queue?maxMessagesPerPoll=5&messageGroupIdStrategy=usePropertyValue")
    .aggregate(const(true), new GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy())
    .completionFromBatchConsumer()
    .process(exchange -> {
        // process ALL messages together as I now have a list of all exchanges
    })
```

but the `processor` is never invoked.

Second thing:
If I'm able to make this work, when does ACK is sent to SQS? When each individual message is processed or when the aggregate process finishes? I hope the latter

Answer (score 1):

When the processor is not called, the aggregator probably **still waits for new messages** to aggregate.

You could try to use `completionSize(5)` instead of `completionFromBatchConsumer()` for a test. If this works, the batch completion definition is the problem.

For the **ACK against the broker: unfortunately no**. I think the message is commited when it arrives at the aggregator.

The Camel aggregator component is a "stateful" component and therefore it **must end the current transaction**.

For this reason you can equip such components with **persistent repositories to avoid data loss** when the process is killed. In such a scenario the already aggregated messages would obviously be lost if you don't have a persistent repository attached.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Indeed using `copmletionSize(5)` did the job. This led me to the solution which I'll post as an answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in `GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy`

When I use this strategy, the output is an "array" of all exchanges. This means that the exchange that comes to the completion predicate no longer has the initial properties. Instead it has `CamelGroupedExchange` and `CamelAggregatedSize` which makes no use for the `completionFromBatchConsumer()`

As I don't actually need all exchanges being aggregated, it's enough to use `GroupedBodyAggregationStrategy`. Then exchange properties will remain as in the original exchange and just the body will contain an "array"

Another solution would be to use `completionSize(Predicate predicate)` and use a custom predicate that extracts necessary value from groupped exchanges.